# rails form placeholder hints disappears immediately after focusing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, placeholder, hint

I am on Rails 3.1 I was trying to use the inline placeholder hint for a text field, I notice that after click on the text field, the hint disappears. Even though that probably was the design, but sometimes people might just not remember what the field was and they caret is already on the field so they have to click elsewhere to make it appear. What I want is not to make it disappear immediately after focusing but after typing a letter (better yet non-space letter). Does anyone know if there is a tweak for this?

More Explicit example

#order.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag do |f| %>
<%= text_field_tag :name, nil, :name => 'company[name]', :placeholder => "Company"  %>
<% end %>
```

So when the field has no data and is NOT focused, you will see the light grey hint "Company" like this:
[image]

And when the field is clicked on, it's like this:

[image]

But I want that the field continues to show the hint "Company" even after it has been clicked on but before anything is entered, like this:

[image]

And the hint "Company" will go away as soon as the user types something in it. Like this:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give us an example of your view showing this problem (not the whole view, just a minimal example of it breaking)

Comment: yes, sorry about that. updating now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of `placeholder` is controlled by the browser, you'll have to use jQuery or similar to get the behaviour you want.

I'd recommend taking a looking at the In-Field Labels plugin ([Demo](http://fuelyourcoding.com/scripts/infield/) - [Github](https://github.com/dcneiner/In-Field-Labels-jQuery-Plugin))

Comment: That. Hit. The. Spot. I see so the placeholder is an, I am guessing, HTML5 thing?

Comment: It is indeed. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute